# Android: SmartFox Server: check room is created or not?

Tags: android, smartfoxserver

I am working in android. I want to create a chat room dynamically using programming.

I am using following code for this:-

```
     private void createNewRoom()
    {
    // Create a new chat Room
     RoomSettings settings = new RoomSettings("MyChatRoom");
     settings.setMaxUsers(40);
     settings.setGroupId("MyChatRoom");
     sfs.send(new CreateRoomRequest(settings));

    }
```

Now i want to see that whether this room is created or not. So please suggest me what should i do to check this ? i want to show this created chat room.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how to create room and how to add friends in that room give me any link and example exaplain with little bit more code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

When we send request to add room dynamically then after your request has sent, we should print list of rooms in that zone.

If you have name of your room in that list this means your room has added.

This code is used to get rooms in particular zone.

```
sfs.getRoomList()
```

I hope this will help you.